# VBA how to copy images / inline shapes from Word to powerpoint

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I am trying to write a macro to find and copy all the graphs/images inline in a word document and paste them into individual slides in a new powerpoint. However when I run into multiple runtime errors. Here's the entire code.

```
Sub wordtoppt()
'This macro copies all pictures out of a word document of your choice and into a new powerpoint presentation.

'Two reference libraries need to be open - Word and Powerpoint. Go Tools > References, and tick the relevant box.


Dim wdApp As Word.Application   'Set up word and powerpoint objects
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptShw As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptChart As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim pptSld As PowerPoint.Slide

On Error GoTo 0

Dim wcount As Integer       'Number of open word documents
Dim doclist() As String     'Collects the names of open word documents
Dim desc As String          'inputbox text
Dim chosendoc As Integer    'stores the index number of your selected word document
Dim ccount As Integer       'number of shapes in the word document

Dim wellpasted As Integer   'Counts the number of shapes that have successfully been pasted into powerpoint.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Establishes link with word.
On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If wdApp Is Nothing Then 'Error message if Word is not open
    MsgBox "Error: Word is not open." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Is word actually open? This is a bug."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Counts the number of word documents open
wcount = CInt(wdApp.Documents.Count)
ReDim doclist(wcount) 'resizes string array of word documents
If wcount = 0 Then 'Error message if Word is open, but there are no documents open
    MsgBox "There are no word documents open!" & Chr(10) & "Open a word document and try again"
    Exit Sub
End If

'text for input box
desc = "Which document would you like to extract the graphs from?" & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Type the number in the box (one number only)." & Chr(10) & Chr(10)

'input boxes for selection of word document
If wcount = 1 Then 'if only one document open
   myinput = MsgBox("Do you want to paste graphs from " & wdApp.Documents(1).Name & "?", vbYesNo, "From Release Note to Powerpoint")
    If myinput = vbYes Then
        chosendoc = 1
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    For i = 1 To wcount 'multiple documents open
        doclist(i) = wdApp.Documents(i).Name
        desc = desc & i & ": " & doclist(i) & Chr(10)
    Next
    myinput = InputBox(desc, "From Release Note to Powerpoint")

    If IsNumeric(myinput) And myinput <= wcount Then 'Error handling - if cancel is clicked, or anything other than a number is typed into the input box.
        chosendoc = CInt(myinput)
    Else
        If myinput = "" Then 'clicking cancel, or leaving input box blank
            MsgBox "You didn't enter anything!"
            Exit Sub
        Else 'if you type a short novel
            MsgBox "You didn't enter a valid number!" & Chr(10) & "(Your response was " & myinput & ")"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End If

'Error handling, for chart-free word documents.
If wdApp.Documents(chosendoc).InlineShapes.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no charts in this Word Document!"
    Exit Sub
End If


'Opens a new powerpoint presentation
Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set pptShw = pptApp.Presentations.Add

'PowerPoint.Application
'Sets up slide dimensions
Dim sldwidth As Integer
Dim sldheight As Integer
sldwidth = pptShw.PageSetup.SlideWidth
sldheight = pptShw.PageSetup.SlideHeight



wellpasted = 0


Dim shapecount As Integer 'Number of shapes in the word document
shapecount = wdApp.Documents(chosendoc).InlineShapes.Count

For j = 1 To shapecount 'Adds in the correct number of slides into the powerpoint presentation
Set pptSld = pptShw.Slides.Add(pptShw.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
Next

For j = 1 To shapecount 'loops through all shapes in the document

On Error GoTo Skiptheloop 'sometimes some objects don't paste. This is a way to skip over them.

'Application.Wait Now + (1 / 86400)

   wdApp.Documents(chosendoc).InlineShapes(j).Range.Copy 'copies chart

   Set pptSld = pptShw.Slides(j)

   pptSld.Shapes.Paste 'pastes chart

'Application.CutCopyMode = False

   With pptSld.Shapes(1)     'resizes and aligns shapes
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue 'Currently sets charts to the height of the slide. Alternatively can scale to 100%
        .Height = sldheight
        .Left = (sldwidth / 2) - (.Width / 2)
        .Top = (sldheight / 2) - (.Height / 2)
   End With
   wellpasted = wellpasted + 1 'if the chart was pasted successfully, increment by 1.

Skiptheloop:
Next


On Error GoTo 0
If (shapecount - wellpasted) <> 0 Then 'produces a message box if some shapes did not paste successfully.
    MsgBox CStr(shapecount - wellpasted) & " (of " & CStr(shapecount) & ") shapes were not pasted. Best that you check all the graphs are in."
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
pptApp.Activate 'brings powerpoint to the front of the screen


Exit Sub

End Sub
```

On the line `pptSld.shapes.paste` I get the error clipboard empty or cannot paste.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is this code running? If you put a break point in the code after Range.Copy then click in, say, another document does something paste? If not, copy the Range.Copy line and paste it just above then change Copy to Select. Run that line, stopping again and check if the thing you expect is actually selected. Try copying that manually, then start the code again at pptSld.Shapes.Paste to see if that works.

Comment: Note that it would be better if you dimmed a Word.Document object and assigned `wdApp.Documents(chosendoc)` to it, then use that in your code instead of relying on Word not changing the document order...

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you for those suggestions. I tried both and still get the same issue. When I step through, it appears to selects each object fine.

Comment: Don't use clipboard. Its messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Simple solution for my job devided in two pars

1) Extract all images from word file
   This can be done in two ways.

**a.** save as html which will create the folder filenam_files which will hold all the images in `.png` formate. There may be duplicate images in diff formate but `.png` will be unique.

**b.** change filename of word from `file.docx` to `file.docx.zip`
        You can get the images at `file.docx\word\media`
        There will be no duplicate images in this method.

2) Import all images in powerpoint.

**1)**

As you have already opened the document manually you can do one more step manually or record macro which will look like this.

```
Sub exportimages()
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "D:\temp\"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="data.html", FileFormat:=wdFormatHTML, _
    LockComments:=False, passWord:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword _
    :="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
    SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _
    False, CompatibilityMode:=0
End Sub
```

**2)**

Close the word document.
Open Power point and paste this

```
Sub ImportABunch()

Dim strTemp As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFileSpec As String
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oPic As Shape


strPath = "D:\temp\data_files\"
strFileSpec = "*.png" 'if you are using mehtod **a.** to extract the images.
'strFileSpec = "*.*" 'if you are using mehtod **b.** to extract the images.

strTemp = Dir(strPath & strFileSpec)

Do While strTemp <> ""
    Set oSld = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
    Set oPic = oSld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPath & strTemp, _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
    Left:=0, _
    Top:=0, _
    Width:=-1, _
    Height:=-1)
    strTemp = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

You can write vbscript to combine this two steps together. I have no idea how to do that. You can google it.